# Gradient of function composed with linear transformation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

In one dimension we have the following easy result, $\frac{d}{dx} f(ax) = af'(ax)$ for any constant $a$.

In higher dimensions, we have two "reasonable" candidates for $\frac{d}{d\mathbf{x}}f(A\mathbf{x})$, namely $A \nabla f(A \mathbf{x})$ and $A^T \nabla f(A \mathbf{x})$.

By bashing out the algebra I can verify that the correct answer is the second option, but can an experienced mathematician explain why it's *obviously* the second one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The chain rule (which you can look up) says that if we define $g(\mathbf x) = f(A\mathbf x) = (f\circ T)(\mathbf x)$, then
$$Dg(\mathbf x) = Df(T(\mathbf x))DT(\mathbf x).$$
Since $T(\mathbf x) = A\mathbf x$ is a linear map, $DT = T$, and so we have
$Dg(\mathbf x) = Df(A\mathbf x)A$. If you're looking at the gradient, as opposed to the derivative, then you transpose the equation, since $\nabla g(\mathbf x) = \big(Dg(\mathbf x)\big)^\top$, and you get your second equation.

Comment: I mixed up the symbols, sorry.

Comment: So, do you understand my explanation?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I didn't know about $D$ and $\nabla$ and their relationship.  I guess I really didn't understand the multivariable chain rule.

Comment: Where can I read more about $D$ and $\nabla$, and about why one is the transpose of the other?

Comment: @becko It's pretty standard stuff, in any serious multivariable analysis book. I'm fond of my own, or see my lectures on YouTube. They are both in my profile.

Comment: "D" seems like nonstandard notation here, for what it's worth. Various sources also disagree on what "the chain rule" for matrix analysis is. So don't expect to be able to simply look up "the multivariable chain rule" in another source and have it look like this. I wish the various forms of matrix analysis would come to an agreement on what notation & layout conventions to use....

Comment: @lacker I disagree. $D$ and $d$ are both used for the derivative as a linear mapping. I am not prepared to say with what relative frequency. The gradient is always a vector; the derivative is always a linear map.